# DXA 2.0 CTP website internal server error

Tags: dxa, web8.5

I have just setup the DXA 2.0 CTP in Web 8.5. I have published all the Pages but when I try to load up the home page I get an internal server error.

In the Logs, I find that the new Model Service is not able to the page. Even though the page has been published and I can see it in the database. Has anyone come across this?

> 017-06-22 10:07:59,222 [13] DEBUG - Determined Device Family: 'desktop'
>       2017-06-22 10:15:19,518 [51] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://localhost:81/' 
>       maps to Localization [7 ('English')]
>       2017-06-22 10:15:19,606 [51] DEBUG - No value cached for key '/:True' in 
>       region 'PageModel'.
>       2017-06-22 10:15:19,607 [51] DEBUG - Sending DXA Model Service Request: 
>       http://localhost:8998/PageModel/tcm/7/index?includes=INCLUDE
>       2017-06-22 10:15:19,616 [51] ERROR - Object reference not set to an 
>       instance of an object.
>       System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of 
>       an object.
>       at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.ModelServiceClient.LoadData[T](Uri 
>       requestUri) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\ModelServiceClient.cs:line 99 at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.DefaultContentProviderR2.LoadPageModel(String& urlPath, Boolean addIncludes, Localization localization) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\DefaultContentProviderR2.cs:line 83

## update

After publishing Components (as DCP), I now get this new error:

> 017-06-22 11:25:36,321 [228] ERROR - DXA Model Service returned an error 
>       response: Status=500, Error='Internal Server Error', 
>       Exception='com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException', 
>       Message='com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Invalid escape 
>       sequence at line 1 column 570 path $.claimValues..DOCUMENT_ROOT', 
>       Path='/PageModel/tcm/7/index'
>       2017-06-22 11:25:36,321 [228] ERROR - DXA Model Service returned an 
>       error: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Invalid escape 
>       sequence at line 1 column 570 path $.claimValues..DOCUMENT_ROOT
>       Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: DXA Model Service returned an error: 
>       com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Invalid escape sequence at 
>       line 1 column 570 path $.claimValues..DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: Your new error makes it look like some of your content is published with a different template than the DXA templates

Comment: Also check the Model Service log file(s). It may provide more information where the problem lies exactly.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue make sure to publish the following 2 items in CMS.

1. **Sitemap [Navigation]** - Categories and Keywords

   [image]
2. **Generate Data Presentation** - Dynamic Component Presentation (DCP)

   [image: **enter image description here**]

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/52

DXA 2.0 CTP requires Components to be published as DCPs - I *assume* that this will change before actual release.

Comment: Unfortunately publishing as DCP did not resolve the issue,  but now I get a different error